# Adjoint of adjoint of a matrix

Tags: matrices

I know $ adj ( A^{-1})   = \frac {A}{|A|}$

But on implying $A^{-1} = \frac {adj A} {|A|}$ to the above, I get

$adj   \frac {adj A} {|A|} = \frac {A}{|A|}$

Which shows adj adj A = A, which is not true. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Do you assume $\mathrm{adj}(kA) = k\,\mathrm{adj}(A)$?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cancel out $|A|$ . Actually  $adj( cA) =c^{n-1} adj(A)$ if  $c$ is  scalar? (where $n$ is the number of rows/columns).

Comment: Is it a statement or a question?